# Hive or Hbase when we need to pull more number of columns?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I have a data structure in Hadoop with 100 columns and few hundred rows. Most of the times I need to query 65% of columns. In this case which is better to use HBASE or HIVE? Please advice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! It makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Just number of columns you are accessing is NOT the criteria for deciding hbase or hive.

### HIVE (SQL) :

Use Hive when you have warehousing needs and you are good at SQL and don't want to write MapReduce jobs. One important point though, Hive queries get converted into a corresponding MapReduce job under the hood which runs on your cluster and gives you the result. Hive does the trick for you. But each and every problem cannot be solved using HiveQL. Sometimes, if you need really fine grained and complex processing you might have to take MapReduce's shelter.

### Hbase (NoSQL database):

You can use Hbase to serve that purpose. If you have some data which you want to access real time, you could store it in Hbase.

hbase `get 'rowkey'` is powerful when you know your access pattern

#### Hbase follows CP of CAP Theorm

#### Consistency:

Every node in the system contains the same data (e.g. replicas are never out of data)

#### Availability:

Every request to a non-failing node in the system returns a response

#### Partition Tolerance:

System properties (consistency and/or availability) hold even when the system is partitioned (communicate lost) and data is lost (node lost)

[image]

also have a look at [this](http://www.smartdatacollective.com/mtariq/120791/hadoop-toolbox-when-use-what)

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to answer the question in one line.

HBASE is NoSQL database: your data need to store denormalized data because HBASE                         is very bad for joi

ning tables.

Hive: You can store data in similar format (normalized) in Hive, but would only see benefits when doing batch processing.